# Autohotkey Fn key remapping on Logitech k750 keyboard

Tags: autohotkey, logitech

I've googled, read forums but unsucceed in this.
Tried "Mystery of the Fn key" [http://www.autohotkey.net/~daonlyfreez/tutorials/3p/Veil/fnkey.htm](http://www.daonlyfreez.net/tutorials/3p/Veil/fnkey.htm)
But stucked at AutoHotkeyRemoteControlDLL.ahk, that doesn't react on my Fn key on all devices (1-5 HID, 6-9 Keyboard, 10-16 mouse).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you place the `AutoHotkeyRemoteControlDLL.ahk` in the "C:\Users\YOURACCOUNTNAME\Documents\AutoHotkey\Lib" directory?

Comment: first you can try sniffing whether the keyboard does transmit the `Fn` key or not. If not, then any driver or remapper won't work. Article http://julien.danjou.info/blog/2012/logitech-k750-linux-support can guide you, they used Wireshark under Windows with k750.

Comment: Please check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24927828/1601703 . Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the Function key called in Auto Hotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435328/what-is-the-function-key-called-in-auto-hotkey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is, that a lot of keyboards don't implement it as normal key, but as a modifier that changes the key messages of other keys pressed at the same time.

So here is an example scenario of how Windows could see your input:

Press F1 down - Windows receives the F1 down code
Press F1 up - Windows receives the F1 up code
Press Fn down - Windows doesn't get anything
Press F1 down - Windows  receives the media ▶ down code
Press F1 up - Windows  receives the media ▶ up code
Press Fn up - Windows doesn't get anything