# What is the Function key called in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey, keyboard-events

I have a key labelled <kbd>Fn</kbd> in blue letters at the bottom of my Windows 7 keyboard. I want to trigger my AutoHotkey script whenever someone presses that key.

What is the Function key called in AutoHotkey?

Comment: Try to find out the scan code of this key (if it has any) via key history.

Comment: @user3419297  I pressed the key, then F5 (refresh)- it turns up with nothing as if I didn't press the key.

Comment: Read in the manual: http://ahkscript.org/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys (Alternate solutions)

Comment: ive red it, pretty sure its a software that has higher authorities that AKH, but im stuck here.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is, that a lot of keyboards don't implement it as normal key, but as a modifier that changes the key messages of other keys pressed at the same time.

So here is an example scenario of how Windows could see your input:

Press F1 down - Windows receives the F1 down code
Press F1 up - Windows receives the F1 up code
Press Fn down - Windows doesn't get anything
Press F1 down - Windows  receives the media ▶ down code
Press F1 up - Windows  receives the media ▶ up code
Press Fn up - Windows doesn't get anything